# Disable Drop Down Option using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, web-deployment

I need to disable options with value "- Sold Out -" in a list of dynamic drop down menus. How can I do this easily with jQuery? Below is the HTML

```
<select id="field_0_1" class="text_select" name="field_0_1" onChange="">
<option value="">- Preferred Time -</option>
<option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option>
<option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">2:30 - 4:00pm</option>
</select>
<select id="field_0_2" class="text_select" name="field_0_2" onChange="">
<option value="">- Preferred Time -</option>
<option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option>
<option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">2:30 - 4:00pm</option>
</select>
<select id="field_0_3" class="text_select" name="field_0_3" onChange="">
<option value="">- Preferred Time -</option>
<option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option>
<option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">2:30 - 4:00pm</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
$("select option[value*='Sold Out']").prop('disabled',true);
        ​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BYkVW/2/)**

#### According to edit

```
$('#previous_select').on('change', function() {
   // after creating the option
   // try following
   $("select option[value*='Sold Out']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: LIfe is good bruv! `:)` wasn't well bruv, and was busy travelling from work.

Comment: Thanks guys, but my drop down is a dependant drop down and it populates <option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option> when I select the previous drop down. So it doesnt get disabled with the script you provided. Whats the solution for that? How can I make it run the jquery once they change the drop down? Hope I make sense

Comment: Sorry, it didnt work either. Sorry. can you have a look at this link www.fitfixtraining.com.au/formtest/form.php Its a similar form as I have, in this case, I want to disable Alberta?

Comment: i changed .chagne to .click and it worked. But on IE, the drop down dissapears once clicked, and have to click it again

Answer (score 9):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/BYkVW/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/BYkVW/1/

Hope it helps the needs `:)`

**code**

```
$("#field_0_1 option[value='- Sold Out -']").attr('disabled','disabled');
        ​
```

**or**

```
$("#field_0_1 option[value='- Sold Out -']").prop('disabled','disabled');
```

**working image**

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, but my drop down is a dependant drop down and it populates 
<option value="- Sold Out -">- Sold Out -</option> when I select the previous drop down. So it doesnt get disabled with the script you provided. Whats the solution for that? How can I make it run the jquery once they change the drop down?

Comment: Yo @UdaraUragoda can you flick this behaviour in jsfiddle? plz! `:)`

Comment: @UdaraUragoda cool so you second drop down `disable` is depended on the 1st drop down list right? so what is the condition you wnat option to be disabled for? Lemme know and I will flick you the solution. `:)`  or help you out.

Comment: If the second option value has "Sold Out" somewhere within the value, disable it?

Comment: @UdaraUragoda yo brother - I am really finding it hard to understand what are your trying to say - I reckon think about the scenario and flick it across - i.e. you want option `"Sold Out"` disabled everywhere in the select drop down if it exist in multiple place? `:)` dont worry Given I understand I am happy to help you out!

Comment: Sorry. did you have a look at this link www.fitfixtraining.com.au/formtest/form.php

Its a similar form as I have, in this case, I want to disable Alberta?

Comment: i changed .chagne to .click and it worked. But on IE, the drop down dissapears once clicked, and have to click it again

Answer (score 3):

```
function lockDownDropDownList(ddlName) {
    ddlName = "#" + ddlName;
    var chosenValue = $(ddlName).val();

    var downDownListItems = $(ddlName).children('option').map(function (i, e) {
        return e.value || e.innerText;
    }).get();

    downDownListItems.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item != chosenValue)
        {
            $("select option[value*='" + item + "']").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done solution for above query. demo link as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp92

**HTML:**

```
 <select id="field_0_1" class="text_select" name="field_0_1" onChange="">
  <option value="">
    - Preferred Time -
  </option>
  <option value="- Sold Out -">
    - Sold Out -
  </option>
  <option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">
    2:30 - 4:00pm
  </option>
</select>
<select id="field_0_2" class="text_select" name="field_0_2" onChange="">
  <option value="">
    - Preferred Time -
  </option>
  <option value="- Sold Out -">
    - Sold Out -
  </option>
  <option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">
    2:30 - 4:00pm
  </option>
</select>
<select id="field_0_3" class="text_select" name="field_0_3" onChange="">
  <option value="">
    - Preferred Time -
  </option>
  <option value="- Sold Out -">
    - Sold Out -
  </option>
  <option value="2:30 - 4:00pm">
    2:30 - 4:00pm
  </option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("select").click(function() {
        $(this).find("option[value*='Sold Out']").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp92

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants to be able to disable a drop down list by text instead of value, here's what I did:

```
$("#DDL option").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "Text 1" ||
           $(this).text() === "Text 2" ||
           $(this).text() === "Text 3";
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use add class disabled to **md-select-wrapper** 
$("#selectFromMainId").addClass("disabled");

md-select-wrapper disabled disabled