# Block certain options in a HTML drop down box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question or similar has been asked a few times however I can't find a suitable answer. I am creating a website where people can book bus journeys. I have two drop down boxes, both with the same locations. I want it so when a certain departure is selected, only certain locations within the destination drop down box are enabled. For example, if London is selected in the first drop down, you cannot select London or any of the locations in which the bus does not travel to in the second drop down.

Here is our HTML

```
     <b> Departure: </b> &nbsp;
     <select name="leave" id="leave" required>
     <option value="" selected id="disabled">-- Select --</option>
     <option value="Bristol" id="Lbristol"> Bristol </option>
     <option value="Newcastle" id="Lnewcastle"> Newcastle </option>
     <option value="Manchester" id="Lmanchester"> Manchester </option>
     <option value="London" id="Llondon"> London </option>
     <option value="Glasgow" id="Lglasgow"> Glasgow </option>
     </select>

    <b> Destination: </b> &nbsp;
    <select name="arrive" id="arrive" required>
    <option value="" selected id="disabled">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="Bristol" id="Abristol"> Bristol </option>
    <option value="Newcastle" id="Anewcastle"> Newcastle </option>
    <option value="Manchester" id="Amanchester"> Manchester </option>
    <option value="London" id="Alondon"> London </option>
    <option value="Glasgow" id="Aglasgow"> Glasgow </option> 
    </select>
```

We have tried multiple different ideas of JavaScript but can only get it to block out one or all options in the second drop down box.

Here is one of the long ideas of javascript click here [Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a71xto1a/)
I stored it in Jfiddle but don't actually know how to work it so it doesn't run sorry for being pretty useless

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really do that in a way where the user would understand what's going on.  I would recommend loading new values for the destination based on the departure selection using AJAX.

Comment: You can add disabled attribute to ones which are not supposed to be selected.

Comment: *"We have tried multiple different ideas of JavaScript..."* Show us, we will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I have added a link to a jfiddle page which shows the javescript idea we used

Comment: @Peril95 check out my answer below. Is that what you are looking to do? or are you looking for a jQuery independent alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an interesting solution using my favorite, and often underutilized, conditional statement `switch`. You are going to want to disable *destination* dynamically based on the selection in the *departure* `select` element, hence the use of an on `change` handler and simple `switch` statement to delegate *who* should be disabled.

**JQuery**

```
$('#leave').on('change', function () {
$('#arrive').children('option').prop('disabled', false);

switch ($(this).val()) {

    case "Bristol":
        $("#Abristol").prop('disabled', true);
        break;

    case "Newcastle":
        $("#Anewcastle").prop('disabled', true);
        break;

    case "Manchester":
        $("#Amanchester").prop('disabled', true);
        break;

    case "London":
        $("#Alondon").prop('disabled', true);
        break;

    case "Glasgow":
        $("#Aglasgow").prop('disabled', true);
        break;
   }
});
```

Check out the working: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/bt4v846c/3/)

> **NOTE:** 
>   a larger, or rather a lengthier `select` element may call for a `for` loop for both robusticity and concision.

Comment: Thanks it works in JS fiddle but we cannot get it to work using notepadd++ some reason, have you got any suggestions? e.g a certain library

Comment: @Peril95 - Not 100% sure but check for a minimum JS language version of EMCAScript 5.1 and be sure to import jQuery (1.11.0 or greater)

Comment: @Peril95 - **correction** jQuery(1.9.1 or greater), but it never hurts to have the most recent stable version. lol.

Comment: @Peril95 - No problem. Glad I could help. Be sure to check validate my answer...;)

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/bt4v846c/1/

```
$("#Abristol").prop('disabled', true);
$("#Anewcastle").prop('disabled', true);
```

As a sidenote, disabled is it's own property and not put in the ID field.

Relevant question: [Disable Drop Down Option using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752097/disable-drop-down-option-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the option from the dropdown based on a variable in my example its value.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var value = "London";
    $("#arrive option[value='"+value+"']").remove();
  });
```